# Selecting item in UI picker view at runtime or via button

Tags: swift, select, button, runtime, uipickerview

I am using xCode 9 and Swift 3(?). How do you select an item in UI picker view at runtime and/or via button? Once clicked via button, UI picker view must also be updated. Thank you.

[Screenshot for the above inquiry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ0Mi.png)

Comment: Why aren't you using a `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: I tried it. It takes longer to navigate to the calendar date I desired to.

Comment: I do not need the time component of the UI date picker.

Comment: Set the date picker's mode to `.date` and you won't see the time on the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Call `– selectRow:inComponent:animated:` when you click on any of the buttons. See [PickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) for more details.

**EDIT:**

(after you connect your PickerView to your code - it can be called anything)

i.e.:

April:

`myPickerView.selectRow(aprilRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)`

16th Day:

`myPickerView.selectRow(16, inComponent: 1, animated: false)`

Today's Date:

```
myPickerView.selectRow(todaysMonth, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
myPickerView.selectRow(todaysDay, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
etc...
```

Comment: I want to have specific items in the picker view set at runtime or via button. Once the button is clicked, the picker view must also reflect those. Please refer to the provided screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: @LuigiA.Cruz I posted a small example of what I was mentioning

Comment: Did this.

pickerView.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

But it shows this error message:

Ambiguous reference to member 'pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)' .

What will I do with this?

Comment: Solved. UI picker view in view controller must be dragged to source code before I can use those you suggested and must be named pickerView. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry should have clarified that. Glad it worked!